# child div align center on parent div with overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, centering

Hello Stackoverflow Team,

How can the child div inside the parent div with overflow have a right and left margin? I'm trying to solve the issue but it does not give a clean solution for it.

Attempt:

margin-right wont work

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

My unclean Solution:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-right: 20px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

any better way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `position: absolute` for the child, best way to achieve what you want is remove `position: absolute` then add the margins you need.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.child {
    width:350px;
    height:150px;
    top: 50px;
    margin: 50px 20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you need the child div to be `position: absolute` you will have to wrap it in another div as follow:

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child {
  border-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  height: 150px;
}
.sub-child {
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="sub-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i need a position absolute for my parent div?

Comment: it won't affect the child, try to change parent `position: absolute` you will see that the child doesn't affected

Comment: sorry about that i mean what if i need a position absolute for the child div? do I need to put another div inside the child div for this solution to work?